# How to efficiently make Wrapper for MT20x Message

Tags: java

I planned to make a wrapper to **Swift** **MT203, MT204** messages.

Message Structure as follows,

`MT203` - 
 2 Mandatory Sequences, where first one exists once and second one can exists two to ten times, and each sequence can contains mandatory fields and optional fields.

`MT204` -
 2 Mandatory Sequences, where first one exists once and second one can exists more than one time, and each sequence can contains mandatory fields and optional fields.

[References for the MT203 and MT204]

1. https://www2.swift.com/knowledgecentre/publications/usgf_20180720/1.0?topic=finmt203.htm
2. https://www2.swift.com/knowledgecentre/publications/usgf_20180720/1.0?topic=finmt204.htm

Which data structure is better to use to store the second sequences in each cases,

I prefer, Array for instance `MT203`, since I know the maximum size of second sequence but for `MT204` I was confused to choose which is better from array and array list.

As during unpacking we have to get fields continuously but not all fields are mandatory for the second sequences.

[Also do comment if the first one choice of Array is not valid]

Comment: Can the size of such a structure change after its creation? I.e. could it happen that you create an array of a specific size, but then would have to resize it to add further optional fields? (Personally, I'd go with ArrayList unless that turns out to result in performance problems)

Comment: I have two cases, in first one I can used fixed array with fields can be null or filled and in second case I planned to use array list with fields can be null or filled... in sense of memory consumption does these approach are good for making or not

Comment: It seems there should already be a Java library for the SWIFT protocol that one can use instead of rolling their own (but I did not check).

Comment: I don't think you need to consider performance differences here. Both will work well enough that way. As long as you keep this an internal implementation detail that is not exposed to the callers of your wrapper, you can refactor later if you feel like it.

Comment: There is already exists a library, but that doesn't cater the ordering of entries, here I have to create a duplicates of exact message and correctly order it thus helps user to send message without worrying about the order of appending fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd do quite fine with either data structures.

Having said that, there's some things you might want to consider: you can make an ArrayList (like any other list) Immutable. That will prevent unwanted modification of the contents. This might be very interesting when you pass these message objects around and want to prevent someone else to modify the message accidentally. There's many ways to make a list immutable - such as  `Collections.immutableList(myArrayList)` or Guava's `ImmutableList.copyOf(myArrayList)`.

Having said that, I believe that there are more important considerations than features of lists over features of array:

First of all, I would consider having them both use the same data structure - especially if both messages are used in the same part of the codebase, it's going to be very confusing if one message type is an array, while the other one is a list. This might ultimately become a pain in the back as both messages will have to be handled differently. e.g. if you want to log messages - you'll have to do that differently for lists vs arrays.

Secondly, I would recommend, modelling each of these messages as a class. That class would (obviousely) use an array or a list internally to store the message data, but it would also give higher level semantical access to the contents of the message.

say you wanted the ValueDate of MTS203 (field index 1): you'd always need to call dateFormat.parse(message[1]) for that - and everyone would need to remember what index 1 was and how to parse the date string into an actual date object. If you had a class like this:

```
class MultipleGeneralFinancialInstitutionTransfer {
 private List<String> messageData; 

 /** constructor... */

 public Date getValueDate() {
  return parseDate(messageData.get(1)); // imagine parse date being a method to parse the actual format  
 }
}
```

it would be much more convenient to work with that message  - and nobody would need to remember the actual format of that message.

Answer (score 1):

I. Size: Array in Java is fixed in size. We can not change the size of array after creating it. ArrayList is dynamic in size. When we add elements to an ArrayList, its capacity increases automatically.

II. Performance: In Java Array and ArrayList give different performance for different operations.

add() or get(): Adding an element to or retrieving an element from an array or ArrayList object has similar performance. These are constant time operations.

resize(): Automatic resize of ArrayList slows down the performance. ArrayList is internally backed by an Array. In resize() a temporary array is used to copy elements from old array to new array.

III. Primitives: Array can contain both primitive data types as well as objects. But ArrayList can not contain primitive data types. It contains only objects.

IV. Iterator: In an ArrayList we use an Iterator object to traverse the elements. We use for loop for iterating elements in an array.

V. Type Safety: Java helps in ensuring Type Safety of elements in an ArrayList by using Generics. An Array can contain objects of same type of classe. If we try to store a different data type object in an Array then it throws ArrayStoreException.

VI. Length: Size of ArrayList can be obtained by using size() method. Every array object has length variable that is same as the length/size of the array.

VII. Adding elements: In an ArrayList we can use add() method to add objects. In an Array assignment operator is used for adding elements.

VIII. Multi-dimension: An Array can be multi-dimensional. An ArrayList is always of single dimension

Now you can chose as per your need which is better for you

Comment: IX. You cannot make an array immutable, whereas you can have an immutable `List` implementation, avoiding the need for defensive copies and such

Comment: Re VIII: You can have a `List<List<List<String>>>` if you feel like it.

Comment: And for the record: java doesn't have multiple dimensions, not even for arrays. In essence an array[][] isn't much different conceptually from a list of lists.

Comment: @Amit Rai, I know the difference between an array and list, my question is which is efficient in my scenario..